# How can I avoid to define public all methods in a package

Tags: packages, packing

If I have to code a Package and these package use a lot of functions and variables. In spite of, using in every call of function or variable with `namePackage` preffix. I've been used `usage`shortcut for each one of them. But, it makes public for every one of these variables. My question is: there are another way to avoid the prefix(because it is ugly, I think so) and still have methods and variables for private?

```
(* my style *)
BeginPackage["Test`"];
f::usage = "";
(* the following is public, but I don't want to. Nevertheless.
I exposed them, because I don't want to be writing the prefix for the package.*)
var1::usage = ""; 
var2::usage = "";

g::usage = "";
Begin["`Private`"];


f[]:=Module[{},
  var1 = 2;
  var2 = 4;
  g[var1, var2];
];

g[a_,b_]:=2;
End[]

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: If you want `var1`, `var2`, and `g` to be private, just don't put in usage messages for them! Long as you're in the private context (due to `Begin[]`), they're usable without the need to declare their full context.

Comment: you only make usage:: for functions that are to be called from outside. Not for all the variables. It is similar to Java class or C++ class, where you make public functions.